# Create an auto update feature in my python app

Tags: python, auto-update, customtkinter

I am looking for an easy and pythonic way to make update my python app on the users machines. Currently the app is hostet in github and I have release versions, but it would be cool if my users would be able to click a button or run a command and if there is a new version - install.

About an app:
It's a python GUI app built on [customtkinter](https://pypi.org/project/customtkinter/). I can either add a button to trigger the action or have a python script to do this.

So far I tried googling, but I did not find any straghitforward solution for this

Comment: I think what you're looking for is probably to upload your app to pypi (https://pypi.org/), and then the users can update to a new version with pip (`pip install --upgrade <package_name>`)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is to use package manager like `pip` on your Python app.

To use `pip` for your app, you can create a `setup.py` file that specifies the dependencies and metadata for your app. You can also include a version number in the `setup.py` file. When you make changes to your app, you can update the version number and create a new release on GitHub.

To install or upgrade your app, your users can run the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade <package-name>
```

Where `<package-name>` is the name of your app package. You can also create a script that automatically checks for updates and runs this command.

Comment: That's an excellent way, but I don't want to make my code publicly available due to some limitations.